# Type of correlation used by protest in vegan

Tags: r, vegan

The `protest` function in vegan returns a "Correlation in a symmetric Procrustes rotation". My assumption is that it evaluates the linear relationship between two sets of continuous variables (i.e. coordinates), and is therefore a Pearson correlation (rather than Spearman). Is this correct, or is it something more nuanced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vegan.pdf#page=209) does not explicitly state whether `vegan::protest` uses Pearson or Spearman correlation, by doing some testing we can see that `vegan::protest` uses Pearson correlation

```
cor(iris[c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], method="pearson" ) # gives -0.1176
cor(iris[c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], method="spearman" ) # gives -0.1668

library(vegan)
protest(iris[,c("Sepal.Length")], iris[,c("Sepal.Width")]) # gives 0.1176
```

Comment: Actually, the documentation is explicit and says what is used: "‘protest’ uses a correlation-like statistic derived from the symmetric Procrustes sum of squares ss as r = sqrt(1-ss)". In symmetric analysis, this happens to be identical to non-signed Pearson correlation for one-dimensional case. (Thinking about ranks in multivariate space gives me such a headache that I want to forget all about them.)